# Lisp: why does this code throw a "function x is undefined" error?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, ecl

I am trying to create a card guessing game in lisp (ECL). However i get an error.

```lisp
(defun random-card ()
  (coerce '(                                        
    (char (random 4) "SCDH")
    (char (random 13) "A23456789JQK"))
  'string)
)

(defun repeat (x n)
  (if (zerop n)
    nil
    (cons (x) (repeat x (1- n)))))

(print (repeat #'random-card 3))
```

The error:

```
An error occurred during initialization:
The function X is undefined..
```

Is the undefined function X the parameter of repeat? What am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

Common Lisp is a [Lisp-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp#The_function_namespace), which means that functions and variables have different namespaces. That's why you had to write `#'random-card` rather than just `random-card`. `random-card` as an argument looks in the *value* namespace. `#'random-card` is a shortcut for `(function random-card)`, which looks up the name in the *function* namespace (`function` itself is *not* a function; it's one of a handful of special operators which are *extremely* baked into the Common Lisp system).

So `function` takes a name in the function namespace and binds it to a value. Now you've got a value called `x` in your `repeat` function. `x` is a variable in the value namespace, and when you write `(x)`, Common Lisp is looking in the *function* namespace. That is, it's looking for something that was `defun`ed, `flet`ed, or `labels`ed. To call a function that's stored in a value-level variable, we use [`funcall`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_funcal.htm).

```
(defun repeat (x n)
  (if (zerop n)
    nil
    (cons (funcall x) (repeat x (1- n)))))
```

Comment: Thank you! May i ask another question here in the comments while youre here?

Comment: @LevZagatov I'm glad you found my answer useful. One of the main points of Stack Overflow is to make question-answer pages that are helpful not just to the person asking but to future viewers who happen upon the site from their preferred search engine. So we do prefer that you ask separate questions on separate pages to maximize their usefulness. That being said, there's a nonzero probability that I'll see it anyway, as the Common Lisp community on this site is smaller than some of the mainstream languages. :P

Comment: You probably won't since there is a 90 minute timeout between questions now, sadly

Comment: @LevZagatov That's a shame. You've got 20 reputation, so we could continue this conversation in a chatroom if you like :) https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255071/discussion-on-answer-to-lisp-why-does-this-code-say-function-x-not-defined